# Fatal error call to undefined function geoip_open()

Tags: php, geoip

I have installed the geoip for getting the address based on the remote_server ip in php. I have installed the Geoip package in my system and also i have installed the php5-geoip php extension. But while running the following script it is showing the fatal error.

```
geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

the error is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_open()
```

Comment: Did you restart your httpd server after the installation of php5-geoip ?

Comment: It means `geoip_open()` is undefined.

Comment: Not sure what extension you are using, but if it's [**this one**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php) I don't think there is an geoip_open() function ?

Comment: @jap1968 yes i have restarted the apache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

include the `geoip_inc` file after that it will not show this error and its `maxMind library`not `php extension`

```
include("include/geoip.inc");

$gi = geoip_open("include/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

Comment: yes thanks yogesh it is working fine now